# find the website url when it hits my landing page, like the url

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, http-referer

i want to find out the websites that are people are coming from when they come on my website. so lets say someone comes from google.com or yahoo.com or someone came through email or somewhere else. how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using ASP.NET:

```
Dim myReferrer As String = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

myReferrer now contains the URL of the referring page.

Comment: Note you'll only have a referrer if the user actually clicked on a link. Bookmarks or typing in the URL directly will cause null referrers. (I've also seen privacy software that munges the referer) Make sure you handle these cases in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` should do the trick